# How to block a specific IP on Centos?

Tags: linux, iptables

I currently have a Centos server with iptables and I am currently getting attacks  from several IP addresses to a specific port and I want to block those IPs.

I have tried several ways to block it, and the attack persists.

The attack method is SYN flood, RST & ACK.

I already checked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOl8.jpg) the length of the package to be able to block it, but I put the line and it does absolutely nothing.

EDIT: There are many IP addresses to block so I wanted to see if I could block the direct packet.

Comment: Please quote all your data in the post.

Comment: Are you *attacking* or *attacked*?

Comment: No attacked application specified, not TCP dumps... it would probably be useful developing more the question. Blocking particular IP addresses by hand is a method known not to work since the 90s.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's always recommended to block the IP at Network or Firewall level.

But still if you want to block IP you can use `iptables` or `fail2ban` concepts in Centos.

IPTABLES:

For example, if you want to block the IP x.x.x.x:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <ip> --dport <portno> -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j REJECT
```

To configure failtoban please follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-7)

Comment: Just as a note: Remember that `iptables` will be replaced by `nftables`